# How to set date and time in android preferences?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I want to set date and time in preferences.In my app i am using the custom date&time dialog and want to set the time & date in preferences choose from that dialog.

Function to display date and time picker dialog:

```
public void showDialog() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.date_time_dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");
    set_time = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.set_time);
    dialog.show();
    timepk = (TimePicker)dialog.findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    timepk.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            hour = hourOfDay;
            min = minute;

        }
    });
    datepk = (DatePicker)dialog.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    datepk.init(Year, month, day, new OnDateChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Year = year;
            month = monthOfYear;
            day = dayOfMonth;
        }
    });
```

Function to save date and time in shared preferences:

```
public void setTime(){
    SharedPreferences prefer = getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = prefer.edit();
    preferencesEditor.putInt("Year",Year);
    preferencesEditor.putInt("Month",month);
    preferencesEditor.putInt("Day",day);
    preferencesEditor.putInt("Hour",hour);
    preferencesEditor.putInt("Min",min);
    Boolean flag = preferencesEditor.commit();
    if(flag==true)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Time saved sucessfully!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: post some code... on what you have tried

Comment: Use Shared Preferences. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: Get milliseconds from date and store that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save and retrieve Date in SharedPreferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343014/how-to-save-and-retrieve-date-in-sharedpreferences)

Comment: That may help you:

: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332269/how-to-set-mobile-system-time-and-date-in-android

Comment: @Itay-I don't want to save system date and time.I want to save the time and date i set from my custom date and time picker dialog. Thnx for ur help:)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing each part of the date as a separate preference, storing a single `long` may be a better alternative. The following example (also posted in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/SamWhited/a2c3c382dcaa3ae17bb4)) is a preference that extends a `DialogPreference` to make a pop up asking for the time (this is time only, but you can swap the time picker out for a date picker and update the values in `onDialogClosed` easily enough). It also implements an `OnPreferenceChangeListener` so that you can do something any time you set the new preference (as an example it updates the summary to the new time set):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class TimePreference extends DialogPreference implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {
    private TimePicker picker = null;
    public final static long DEFAULT_VALUE = 0;

    public TimePreference(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
        this.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    protected void setTime(final long time) {
        persistLong(time);
        notifyDependencyChange(shouldDisableDependents());
        notifyChanged();
    }

    protected void updateSummary(final long time) {
        final DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getContext());
        final Date date = new Date(time);
        setSummary(dateFormat.format(date.getTime()));
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        picker = new TimePicker(getContext());
        picker.setIs24HourView(android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getContext()));
        return picker;
    }

    protected Calendar getPersistedTime() {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(getPersistedLong(DEFAULT_VALUE));

        return c;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(final View v) {
        super.onBindDialogView(v);
        final Calendar c = getPersistedTime();

        picker.setCurrentHour(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        picker.setCurrentMinute(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(final boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

        if (positiveResult) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, picker.getCurrentMinute());
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, picker.getCurrentHour());


            if (!callChangeListener(c.getTimeInMillis())) {
                return;
            }

            setTime(c.getTimeInMillis());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(final TypedArray a, final int index) {
        return a.getInteger(index, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(final boolean restorePersistedValue, final Object defaultValue) {
        long time;
        if (defaultValue == null) {
            time = restorePersistedValue ? getPersistedLong(DEFAULT_VALUE) : DEFAULT_VALUE;
        } else if (defaultValue instanceof Long) {
            time = restorePersistedValue ? getPersistedLong((Long) defaultValue) : (Long) defaultValue;
        } else if (defaultValue instanceof Calendar) {
            time = restorePersistedValue ? getPersistedLong(((Calendar)defaultValue).getTimeInMillis()) : ((Calendar)defaultValue).getTimeInMillis();
        } else {
            time = restorePersistedValue ? getPersistedLong(DEFAULT_VALUE) : DEFAULT_VALUE;
        }

        setTime(time);
        updateSummary(time);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(final Preference preference, final Object newValue) {
        ((TimePreference) preference).updateSummary((Long)newValue);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont feel confortable storing time in millis, you can do this:

```
public void storeDate(Date theDate){
   SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
   df.applyPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"); //this is the SQLite timedate pattern

   SharedPreferences pm = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyActivity.this);
   pm.getEditor().putString("date_key", df.format(theDate));
}

public Date retrieveDate() {
   SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
   df.applyPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"); //this is the SQLite timedate pattern

   SharedPreferences pm = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyActivity.this);
   return df.parse(pm.getString("date_key"));  //this may throw an exception you should handle

}
```