# how to save time in shared preferences in android app

Tags: android

i am developing an application in android on daily basis to remind my coming up proceedings for example when i wake up my mobile show me a popup message that it's breakfast time/lunch time so on  and it can be done by specific time that i will provide to my application that following specific timing is for breakfast so on this time it can show me the popup message

Comment: Your question should be improved and needs to be more clear to understand viewers.

Comment: yes i am improving it as english is not my first language but well thanks for ur concern

Comment: read this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343014/how-to-save-and-retrieve-date-in-sharedpreferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Alarm manager, i am sure this will help you .

Comment: it's not helping can you review my question again